# using $(this) for event based functions

Tags: jquery, this

Looking for some input on a couple of things that I'm a little foggy on with regards to jQuery selectors.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Lets say I wanted to make a button blue when I click on it, I could write something like

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
$(this).css('color', 'blue');
}
```

Forget for a second that using css() is bad and I should add a class instead.
Lets say I wanted to addClass instead to the parent div of that button element.
I know I can reach it by climbing up the DOM:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
$(this).parent('#theParentDiv').addClass('make-it-blue');
}
```

But do I have to use this at all?
Wouldn't this method be heavier, and cause for more browser computation than just selecting the id/class like so:

```
$('#theParentDiv).addClass('make-it-blue');
```

When you write a function, does it automatically start looking from the document object and using this is just way to direct it to the element on which you are attempting the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, jQuery DOM traversal is expensive so selecting the proper element comes at a cost when you are going up and down the tree.

To answer your question of what happens when you write a function, it really depends on what you are selecting.

> Browsers help you to get to certain elements
>
> Browsers do provide some helper functions to get to certain types of elements. For example if you want to get DOM element with id header then document.getElementById function can be used like this
>
> ```
> document.getElementById('header')
> ```
>
> Similarly if you want to collect all the p elements in a document then you could use following code .
>
> ```
> document.getElementsByTagName('p')
> ```
>
> However if you want something complex like the one given below then browsers were not much help. It was possible to walk up and down the tree however traversing the tree was tricky because of two reasons: a) DOM spec is not very intuitive b) Not all the browsers implemented DOM spec in same way.
>
> ```
> jQuery('#header a')
> ```
>
> ....
>
> Sizzle gets the selector string ‘.header a’. It splits the string into two parts and stores in variable called parts.
>
> ```
> parts = ['.header', 'a']
> ```
>
> Next step is the one which sets Sizzle apart from other selector engines. Instead of first looking for elements with class header and then going down, Sizzle starts with the outer most selector string.
>
> [How jQuery selects elements using Sizzle - http://blog.bigbinary.com/2010/02/15/how-jquery-selects-elements-using-sizzle.html](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2010/02/15/how-jquery-selects-elements-using-sizzle.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking for parent class? You can addd class directly on button.

```
$(ths).addClass('make-it-blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a performance test for you to see that targeting directly by ID is faster than using .parent() to find the ID.  You can see the results here:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-id-selector-vs-parent-selector

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a trade-off between laziness and performance.

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $('#buttonParent').addClass('blue');
});
```

is faster than

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('blue');
});
```

but imagine if there are multiple buttons, each with their own parents.

Instead of writing

```
$('#buttonParentOne .button').on('click', function() {
  $('#buttonParentOne').addClass('blue');
});

$('#buttonParentTwo .button').on('click', function() {
  $('#buttonParentTwo').addClass('blue');
});
```

you can just write one that targets any button's own parent.

And then imagine that the buttons and their parents are dynamically generated, which would require generating unique IDs for each one. Then imagine that there are multiple types of buttons used on the same page, so each block would require generating different IDs from each other.

There certainly are things you can do to optimize your code for performance, but for the most part, using `.parent()` is fast enough.